# How to find python's Modules/_io/bufferedio.c?

Tags: python, c

I got an error while installing pandas on python virtual environment on windows 10 pc:

```
OSError: raw write() returned invalid length
```

And find how to fix it:

> [I've solved it by modifying this function in python's](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/39149)
>   Modules/_io/bufferedio.c
>
> In _bufferedwriter_raw_write
>
> Replaced
>
> if (n < 0 || n > len) {
>
> by
>
> if ((n < 0 || n > len) && n != len * 2) {
>
> It's very dirty and probably has side effects but it works for me...

But I can't find it python's Modules/_io/bufferedio.c .

Where I can find python's Modules/_io/bufferedio.c ? To change it.

Answer (score 1):

It's in CPython sources: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_io/bufferedio.c

(the 1st link in Google on "bufferedio.c")

You need to compile Python from source with this change (including the installer) and replace your installation with it.

Official release source tarballs can be found at the official site (or you can check out the tag for the release you need from the repository linked to above). The README files in the source have compilation instructions.

Comment: How can I find it and modify on my pc?

Comment: @МаксимУсик updated